# If else function in .bat script + findstr command

Tags: bash, batch-file

```
IF find tcp.client == 1 

(


 findstr tcp.client *_chkpackage.log>summary.txt 
) 

ELSE 
(

#write only "filename" & "N/A" >> summary.txt

)
```

i want to search a file that search some value in all text files in folder 
if found the  line that contain information i need it is going to write that line to text fiel
if not found the it will  write only filename and "N/A" to the line

i know it wrong  but my coding skill suck so i have to ask

thank you so much for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the dot is a dot and not a regex wildcard, in which case you need to tell FINDSTR to do a literal search.

FINDSTR returns success if found, error if not found. The `||` operator conditionally executes commands if the prior command failed.

Use FOR loop to get each file individually, and add an additional file (nul) that will never match to force inclusion of file name in output.

Enclose entire construct in parentheses and redirect the entire block

```
@echo off
>summary.txt (
  for %%F in (*_chkpackage.log) do findstr /l "tcp.client" "%%F" nul||echo %%F N/A
)
```

Comment: @eathapeking - If you get a good post that fully answers your question and meets your needs then you should accept it by clicking on the check mark near the upper left corner. That action lets others know the question has been answered, it awards you 2 rep points, and awards the answer poster 15 points. Only one answer can be accepted per question. Once you reach 15 rep points you gain the privilege to up vote any answer you find useful, including answers to other people's questions. An up vote awards 10 points to the answer poster.

Comment: yep i did it :) but why it have to be only 1 check for the best answer T^T

everyone should get mark for answer

Answer (score 4):

Something that works according to your "specification" would be that one:

```
@echo off
if exist summary.txt del summary.txt
for %%f in (*_chkpackage.log) do (
  find "tcp.client" %%f>NUL:
  IF errorlevel 1 (
    echo %%f N/A >> summary.txt
  ) ELSE (
    findstr "tcp.client" %%f >> summary.txt
  )
)
type summary.txt
```

Note that the `if errorlevel 1` means "if errorlevel is greater or equal 1", for that I swapped your comparison, because `if errorlevel 0` is true even when errorlevel equals 1.

Comment: Your success output is missing the filename prefix. Also, FINDSTR sets its own errorlevel, so no need for the extra FIND step.

Comment: Hmm. In the success case there was no filename-prefix requested. So the extra find was intruduced to handle these different cases of output :-)

Comment: It was not explicitly requested, but the OP code uses FINDSTR with a wild card in the filespec, which results in the file name being prefixed to each matching line. I'm quite sure the OP would like to keep that functionality. You removed the wildcard, which removes the name prefix from the output.

Comment: Look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13683895/1012053) for a concise way to sove the problem :)